# How to allow my PHP app to write to a file on my AWS?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, codeigniter, web, permissions

I have a codeigniter app that grabes and then pushes data from one database to another. This process takes a large amount of time, and I want to update my user of what files are being queried and pushed. I decided that the best solution was to write the progress messages to a txt file and have my front-end page (index.php) use ajax to send a request for the message by fetching it. I use a session to create a unique session token and use that to create the name of the txt file. This way, no two users will get each other's messages.

I managed to get this working on localhost, but the problem now is how I get it to work on my live server with the proper permissions. I uploaded the code to my server and received this error when trying to run:

```
Severity: Warning Message: 
file_put_contents(application/tmp/d9jf9d9f9jdd9jfd09u09dj0sjf9s0.txt): failed to open stream: 
Permission denied
```

On localhost, I chmodded the application/tmp directory, so this wasn't a problem, but I can't seem to do this on the AWS live server, at least, not permanently (also a bad practice, I hear). Is there an alternative solution to this problem?

Comment: You can just give the write permissions to the web server (`www-data` in the case of `apache`).

Comment: You need to set read-write permissions for the right user (or group) that's running the web server software AND the one doing the upload job (if different). Otherwise consider using a table.

Comment: @tamrat I have, and I still get the wrror

Comment: @Gavin I see. so both the directory and the code the writes to it need to have the same permissions?

Comment: "I decided that the best solution was to write the progress messages to a txt file and have my front-end page (index.php) use ajax to send a request for the message by fetching it"...websockets might be a better solution

Comment: @ADyson I'm a total newb, but how would I implement websocks in a codeigniter app?

Comment: there are ready-made PHP implementations of websockets available online. There might even be something already available specifically to work with codeigniter. Did you have a look around? (Hint: type "php websockets codeigniter" into google...)

Comment: @ADyson They say websockets doesn't work with codeigniter out of the box. Do you know how to add it?

Comment: websockets isn't available with anything "out of the box". You have to add the functionality. Like I said, do a search. The first link on my results was a ready-made websocket plugin for codeigniter, for example, with instructions for how to set it up. There seemed to be a few similar ones. I haven't used any of them myself, so you'll have to decide what you like best. But the information is there, if you care to look.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks! I'll do more research. Websockets is secure, yes?

Comment: @ADyson You mean this one? I had an error trying to add it with compser https://packagist.org/packages/takielias/codeigniter-websocket

Comment: websockets is as secure as anything else on the web, as long as you use HTTPS

Comment: Anyway if you don't tell people what error you got, it's unlikely anyone can help you with it

Comment: @ADyson True, but now I'm thinking I should try EventSource instead ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource). Web sockets seems overkill for this sort of data. Is EventSource a good idea or is their some caveat I don't know about?

Comment: Event source would be fine as long as the information only goes from server to browser, and never the other way round. Watch out for lack of support in Edge though (although it's coming soon I think).

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for your help! I'm having trouble implementing it, so if you know anything about it, please take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60355241/how-to-implement-eventsource-on-codeignigter-app